# Pass by reference and storing a reference to a variable - c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, reference, pass-by-reference

Am I misunderstanding something about pass by reference?

SomeClass is the IObserver implementer:

```
bool value = false;
provider.Subscribe(new SomeClass(ref value));
while (!value)
{
   provider.GetEvents() //triggers OnNext
}
```

In SomeClass:

```
public SomeClass(ref bool value)
{
   this.value = value;              
}

public void OnNext(object someUpdatedValue)
{
   value = true;
}
```

Value never becomes true and the while loop never breaks. How come? Does assigning the value property of SomeClass to the reference of value not persist?

Edit: After seeing the first two responses my new question is this:

How can I achieve this kind of behavior without using static variables?

Comment: Not in `OnNext`, no. `SomeClass` only holds a reference to the original `value` variable in its constructor.

Comment: If your question has been answered please accept an answer. As you have stated that you now have a new question, post a new question don't just add a question to the original post. This one is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ref` modifier affects the caller, not the callee. It allows you to reassign the caller's variable to "point to" a new value. For example:

```
   bool myValue = true;
   WithoutRef_YouCannotReassign(myValue);
   Console.WriteLine(myValue); // myValue is still true

   WithRef_YouCanReassign(ref myValue);
   Console.WriteLine(myValue); // myValue is now false

   void WithoutRef_YouCannotReassign(bool value) {
      value = false;
   }

   void WithRef_YouCanReassign(bool value) {
      value = false;
   }
```

You're trying to pass *out* a reference to `SomeClass.value`. Normally, that'd work great by just swapping your assignment (remember, you're changing the caller's variable to point at something else)

```
  public SomeClass(ref bool value)
  {
     value = this.value;
  }
```

But, you've got another problem. Since a `bool` is immutable - even though your caller is pointing at the right value, you point your own `value` to something else later by overwriting it:

```
 public void OnNext(object someUpdatedValue)
 {
    value = true; // value is now pointing somewhere else! the caller never got a reference to the somewhere else!
 }
```

So, now, you actually need a wrapper to avoid having to overwrite `SomeClass.value` after you passed a reference out to it:

```
 struct MyBoolWrapper 
 {
     public bool Value { get; set; }
 }

 public SomeClass(ref MyBoolWrapper value)
 {
     value = this.value;
 }

 public void OnNext(object someUpdatedValue)
 {
    value.Value = true;
 }
```

Now, *this* won't work because it's a `struct` (like `bool` is). `struct`s are value types, and so the *value* of it gets copied back. When you change `SomeClass.value`, you're changing a *different* copy again! (This is one reason we tend to prefer immutable structs, like `bool` is).

So, let's change this to a class:

```
 class MyBoolWrapper 
 {
     public bool Value { get; set; }
 }
```

This will work as expected since you end up passing back a *reference* to `MyBoolWrapper` (which doesn't change).

So, now we're working - but let's look at some cleanup. It seems a little silly for our caller to have to `new` a `MyBoolWrapper` just so that we can point it to something else. Let's change that:

```
  MyBoolWrapper wrapper = null;
  provider.Subscribe(new SomeClass(ref wrapper));
```

Well, now it seems silly that we set it to `null`. Since `SomeClass` is providing all the info, let's just make it an `out` (which, essentially, works the same as `ref` just without requiring it to be initialized):

```
  MyBoolWrapper wrapper;;
  provider.Subscribe(new SomeClass(out wrapper));
```

Of course, now it's not even clear why we can't just hold a reference to `SomeClass` directly, and get rid of this whole out/ref dance:

```
 SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();
 provider.Subscribe(someClass);

 while (!someClass.Value) {
     provider.GetEvents();
 }

 class SomeClass {
     public Value { get; private set; }

     public void OnNext(object someUpdatedValue)
     {
        Value = true;
     }
 }
```

There - that's simpler. Since the caller has a *reference* to our instance that changes *it's state* (without changing it's *identity*), we don't have to worry about all of that method calling by-ref/by-val struct vs class mumbo-jumbo.

Answer (score 2):

Pass by reference affects only the variable passed as the argument to the method. In your example, the *value* of `false`, which is what the variable `value` contained when you assigned it to `this.value`, is copied to the `this.value` field. Nothing more.

There's nothing magical in C# that will remember *where* that value came from and update the variable later, when the field to which its value was assigned is changed later.

> Does assigning the value property of SomeClass to the reference of value not persist?

You aren't assigning "the reference of value". All that happens when you pass by-reference is that if the local variable itself is changed, then the variable that was passed is modified. When you use the value of the variable, you're only using the value, not the reference.

**EDIT:**

Without more context, it's impossible to say what the best way to approach this would be. But note that reference types achieve something similar to what you seem to be trying to do. For example:

```
class VolatileBoolWrapper
{
    public bool Value { get { return _value; } }
    private volatile bool _value;

    public void SetValue(bool value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }
}
```

```
VolatileBoolWrapper value = new VolatileBoolWrapper();
provider.Subscribe(new SomeClass(value));
while (!value.Value)
{
   provider.GetEvents() //triggers OnNext
}
```

```
public SomeClass(VolatileBoolWrapper value)
{
   this.value = value;              
}

public void OnNext(object someUpdatedValue)
{
   value.SetValue(true);
}
```

In that way, the `VolatileBoolWrapper` class acts as a go-between for the caller and callee.

**<edit>**
Note that I marked the field as `volatile`, and named the class `Volatile...` just to be safe. There's not enough context in the question for me to know what "triggers" actually means (i.e. does the same thread actually set the value, or is this something that involves interaction between threads).

If it happens that the call to `OnNext()` occurs within the same thread, strictly by virtue of the call to `GetEvents()`, then you can omit the use of `volatile` here (and ignore, or at least discount, my note about polling below).

**</edit>**

All that said, frankly: polling on a variable like this is pretty much always the wrong way to accomplish one's goals. There have always been much better approaches for things like this, but in modern C#, I would say that `TaskCompletionSource` is the best alternative. Like other mechanisms that came before it, it allows your waiting code to not continually use CPU time checking to see if the event has occurred; unlike them, it also provides an excellent mechanism for allowing *that entire thread* to continue executing, performing other work, only resuming at the `await` statement where you waited for the event when that event actually occurs.

Comment: So there is no way to achieve what I am trying to do without some sort of static variable? I want to avoid using static variables here if possible.

Comment: Why volatile? There's no evidence of multi threading here... @Pipeline - this is not a static variable; it's just wrapped in an object.

Comment: @Mark: _"Why volatile"_ -- you're right that there's no evidence of multi-threading. But it's also not 100% clear there _isn't_ multi-threading. I added that "just in case". I will clarify my reasoning in the answer.

Comment: @Mark: note that the comment from the OP regarding static is prior to, and the impetus for, my edit showing an actual code example to avoid the problem (the original question was more along the lines of "why doesn't this work?", while the OP subsequently edited the question to add "how can I do this without static variables?")

Comment: @PeterDuniho - good point; it is certainly possible there's some multithreading here...That said, my answer attempts to take a stab at the original confusion directly since the multi-threading angle opens up an entirely different set of considerations and is more advanced than the basic by-ref/by-val divide. +1 for the completeness and warning, though as I think you're right after review.

Comment: @Mark: yes you are right that I have limited my answer to the strictest reading of the question. A person could put a lot of effort into trying to infer the actual usage/implementation of the code in the question, only to find later they guessed wrong. So I prefer to wait for clarification from the OP. YMMV. :)

Comment: Yes I apologize for my lack of clarity, but in my case there is multithreading between them. I accepted your answer for the original question

Comment: @Pipeline: _"I accepted your answer for the original question"_ -- just to be clear: you did not accept _my_ answer. You accepted the other one. As long as you make sure the field is `volatile`, the other answer's approach should work as well. I just want to make sure you accepted the answer you wanted to, and especially that you understand that the code in the other answer is not actually quite correct as-is (since you say there _is_ multithreading involved)..